# i have hive external table and i can show it ,but i can't use it

Tags: hadoop, centos, hive

I have hadoop-2.6.0 on censos7 and hive-0.14

and i configure

```
hive.metastore.warehouse.dir = /user/hive/warehouse
```

so I create external table by stock.hql

```
create external table if not exists nstocks(
...)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
location '/user/hadoop/stock' ( *.csv path )
```

I can show table nstcosk and describe table

[show tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91gop.png)

[descibe formatted nstocks(external table)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3ngR.png)

but i can't found browsing hdfs (locatlhost:50070)

and i can't use this two statement

```
time hadoop jar hadoop-mpareduce-examples-2.6.0.jar wordcount /user/hive/warehouse/nstocks /out/3

time hadoop jar hadoop-mpareduce-examples-2.6.0.jar wordcount /user/hadoop/stock/nstocks /out/3
```

because

```
Input path does not exist: hdfs .... /nstocks Exception
```

If you see describe formatted nstocks(picture) 
nstocks table locations is /user/hadoop/stock

or hive.metastore.warehouse.dir = /user/hive/warehouse

I cant understand this probles T_T 
How can i solve this problem help me plz